# libCurl function curl_easy_perform(cp) causes segfault

Tags: c, curl, segmentation-fault, libcurl, manjaro

For some reason the code below keeps segfaulting. I genuinly don't know what is wrong. I have looked through the curl api docs multiple times, but I still cannot figure out why my program is segfaulting. Using comments I figured out that `curl_easy_perform(cp);` is the culprit. Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("ERR: No arguments given\n");
    return 1;
  }
  if (argc > 2) {
    printf("ERR: %i is too many arguments\n", argc - 1);
    return 1;
  }
  char url[100] = "https://dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/";
  strcat(url, argv[1]);
  strcat(url, "?key=lolno");
  char data[200] = "";
  CURL* cp = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(cp, CURLOPT_URL, url);
  curl_easy_setopt(cp, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (char*)data);
  curl_easy_perform(cp);
  curl_easy_cleanup(cp);
  curl_global_cleanup();
  printf("%s\n", data);
  return 0;
}
```

I am sure that there is some stupid thing I am missing, but I cant figure out what.

Comment: Are you compiling and running the code on Windows?

Comment: no, this is on Manjaro Linux

Comment: I suspect the problem to be with `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`. Check this https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html